# Is heap (heapq) in python stable?

Tags: python, heap

if heaptify this `[(10,'Mike'),(20,'Jack'),(10,'Bob')]`

And return the min of the heap, will it guaranteed to return `(10,'Mike') and not (10,'Bob')` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

no `heapq` is not stable. as stated in the [examples of the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/heapq.html?highlight=heapq#basic-examples)

> This is similar to sorted(iterable), but unlike sorted(), this
>   implementation is not stable.